# Unable to interact with element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From following HTML code snippet, I've to click on radio button with value `Same as user name`

```
<fieldset class="setPwd" style="padding:0.769rem 1.15rem;">
        <legend>Set Password </legend>
        <input type="radio" name="scheme" id="New" value="Default" checked="">Default
        <input type="radio" name="scheme" id="Username" value="Same as user name">Same as user name
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" style="display:none">
        <input type="password" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false" id="password" name="password" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" style="width:66%;padding:0.00rem;">
</fieldset>
```

hence to click on it, I've -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).click();
```

But it results into an error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DT01', ip: '192.16', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.116, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\gajanan\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54490}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: eedc94ffa7211db6c7252bb85421992a

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at org.test.selenium.FramTestBhanu.highlightParentElementTest(FramTestBhanu.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Is there something I should correct in way of identifying element considering its html snippet?

**NOTE** Manually I can click element.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for that element to visible

```
 if (!driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).isSelected()) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).click();
    }
```

use this code segment

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following css selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("fieldset.setPwd input#Username")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure this out after spending an hour or so. First I moved to the element and then clicked on it like -

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("Username")));
actions.click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your XPath is just fine and the other XPath provided in the answers will also work but the thing is you need to add some wait for the element to be visible or clickable If you will not use any kind of Wait then selenium will go and try to find the element only once and it will not repeat the process.

1. You can use either implicit wait or Explicit wait personally I would recommend you to use the explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Username)));

//above lines wait for the element to be visible 

//once it is visible you can click on that 

driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).click();
```

PS: Benefit of Explicit wait is that it will wait for element maximum for the given time in our case it is 15 is the element is visible before that it will not wait until then in implicit wait it will wait for complete-time mentioned